# Two notations for unit tangent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, notation, terminology

A curve in the plane is given by $t\mapsto (x(t),y(t)).$

It seems that textbooks often say $\displaystyle \text{unit tangent vector} = \frac{(x'(t),y'(t))}{\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}}.$

But one can also write $\displaystyle \text{unit tangent vector} = \frac{(dx,dy)}{\sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2}}.$

- How widespread is the use of the latter "Leibniz" notation?

I also have these other two questions whose answers may be a bit "opinion-based":

- In view of the fact that Leibniz probably never saw this expression, would anyone object to calling it "Leibniz" notation?
- What would people consider to be the pros and cons of the two notations?

Comment: This is the first time I have ever seen this second notation. How much older is it? I've read a bit of a lot of DG books, but I guess they're fairly recent. If isn't too much of a bother, can you point some references for this "Leibniz" notation?

Comment: According to the conventions I'm familiar with, $dx$ and $dy$ are $1$-forms, whereas $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ are tangent vectors. So the first notation makes much more sense.

Comment: @IvoTerek : I didn't come across it in a book, but I found it convenient. I was looking at the curvature of the parabola $y=x^2,$ so I said $dy = 2x\,dx$ and then the unit tangent vector was $T = \dfrac{(1,2x) \, dx}{\sqrt{(dx)^2 + (2x\,dx)^2}} = \dfrac{(1,2x)}{\sqrt{1+4x^2}},$ and then I found $ \dfrac {dT}{dx}$ by applying the quotient rule twice, and then found the norm of that vector and simplified it. $\qquad$

Comment: @AmitaiYuval : Can you be explicit about how you run into problems by using this notation?

Comment: This seems to have worked just fine because you used the parametrization of a graph. How would you tackle a circle $x^2+y^2=1$ this way, for example? Ok, $x\,{\rm d}x+y\,{\rm d}y = 0$, but what would you do from there? Writing ${\rm d}y/{\rm d}x = -x/y$ is cheating :P

Comment: I've never seen the latter notation. It makes sense however if we interpret $dx$ and $dy$ as infinitesimals and use the fact that $dx=x'(t)dt$ and  $dy=y'(t)dt$.

Comment: @IvoTerek : The unit tangent vector for that circle is $(-y,x).$ If one writes $$x=\cos \theta ,\qquad y=\sin\theta,$$ then one has $$dx = -y\,d\theta, \qquad dy = x\, d\theta,\qquad \sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2} = d\theta,$$ so the result follows. One can also write $$x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}, \qquad y = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$$ and then $$dx = -2y\frac{dt}{1+t^2}, \qquad dy = 2x\dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}, \qquad \sqrt{(dx)^2 + (dy)^2} = 2\frac{dt}{1+t^2}.$$

Comment: @Michael, one year later I guess I can appreciate your question better. And while I still think that writing $${\rm d}y/{\rm d}x = -x/y $$is cheating, I don't think that writing ${\rm d}y = (-x/y){\rm d}x$ is, since we just solving for a $1$-form in terms of the other. Eliminating ${\rm d}y$ allows for simplification $$T = \frac{(1,-x/y){\rm d}x}{\sqrt{({\rm d}x)^2+(-(x/y){\rm d}x)^2}} =(y,-x), $$using that $x^2+y^2=1$ again. Funny that we got the other orientation, though.